# Alternative Way of UltraSurf for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, networking, proxy, server

I used to use Ultrasurf for bypassing proxy. However, I can't find any way to pass through proxy on Ubuntu. There is some free proxy websites like  http://hideme.be , basically, does same work, but it is not convenient enough. And I don't want to use TOR either.

Besides, I can't even make ssh connection in this situation. I tried to use vpn service and it doesn't work either.

This is how I connect to proxy server for accessing internet:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have any cloud (virtual) server you can ssh to it by using following command through terminal:

```
ssh -o "ProxyCommand=nc -X connect -x proxyhost:proxyport %h %p" -D 1080 -C user@your_ip
```

Once you do that, just delete HTTP/HTTPS/FTP proxies and change SOCKS to **127.0.0.1 : 1080**.

I had the same problem, this worked for me.